# imap_search just message contents for exact string

Tags: php, imap

I have a list of emails that match a particular subject:

```
$ms = imap_search($imap, 'SUBJECT "'.$subj.'"');
if(!is_array($ms)){if($ms===false){$ms=array();}else{$ms=array($ms);}}
```

And i'm looking to see if there's any within that list that also contain a specific search term:

```
$msAZ   = imap_search($imap, 'BODY "'.$term.'"'); 
if(!is_array($msAZ)){if($msAZ===false){$msAZ=array();}else{$msAZ=array($msAZ);}}

$msAZa=array_intersect($ms,$msAZ);
```

Setting aside the whole forcing things into arrays for consistency, I'm sure there's a more efficient and exact way to do this.

Specifically:

can this be done in one step instead of this crazy intersection?

is there a way to at least only look in the email message text itself and not the whole BODY (i.e. exclude attachments)?

also, this seems to be finding some inexact matches (e.g.  $term = "List Contents:  Full" finds emails with spreadsheets where one cell contains "List Contents" and the next cell "Full"). is there a way to make the search match the exact string?

Comment: You can combine both search terms:  search(‘BODY “xxxx” SUBJECT “Yyyy”).  Some server software doesn’t handle complex searches well.

Comment: Thanks Max. i was previously warned against doing that, but i'm not clear on why. perhaps i'll give that another try. honestly, the bigger question for me is the 2nd one.

Comment: Depends on server software.  That should be an exact match by default.

Comment: that's the 3rd one

Comment: Specific sections: no.  IMAP protocol doesn't have a concept for which part is "main" , and doesn't have language for searching message parts.

Comment: not doubting you, but that's very surprising. both because it's such a common thing to want and because imap_fetchstructure can actually tell the difference.

Comment: Fetch structure can show it to you, yes, but to it, all parts are equally important.  (Presumably, most servers will limit searches to text/* parts, though)